# How to change the apperance of the cursor in an EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to change the appearance of cursor/marker in an EditText.  In general the cursor looks like this: 
|
and is flashing.
I want it to look like a black rectangle (the size of 1 character) that is flashing.  Like the standard cursor used in a unix terminal.
Is this possible?

Comment: Accepted answer is false. Here's an answer, [Can I change the Cursor size in android edit text field?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6225995/can-i-change-the-cursor-size-in-android-edit-text-field

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There is no way to change the appearance of the cursor, without re-implementing TextView and android.text.Layout. The cursor's appearance is hardcoded in [getCursorPath()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Layout.html#getCursorPath%28int,%20android.graphics.Path,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) method.

Comment: This is not true now, you can set the android:textCursorDrawable for EditText to use a customized drawable as the cursor.

Comment: @Ray the method you are mentioning is supported only for api 12 and above

Answer (score 1):

This question may help you... [Set EditText cursor color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238450/set-edittext-cursor-color)
This talks about the similar things you want to achieve.