# Can i change the Cursor size in android edit text field?

Tags: android

I want to change the width and color of the cursor that blinks in an Android EditText field. Is that possible?

Answer (score 27):

**res/drawable/cursor_red.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <size 
        android:width="5dip" />
    <solid
        android:color="@color/red" />
</shape>
```

**in your EditText:**

```
android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/cursor_red"
```

note: only API 12 and above

Comment: how can i implement it from the code and change width dynamically? any idea!

@vinc3m1

Comment: create multiple drawable and change the drawable