# How to change edit text cursor color and width in android

Tags: android

I'm developing a new app where i need to customise EditText cursor colour and width of cursor. Can any one please guide me.It will be appriciable.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11649234/change-edittext-cursor-color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11649234/change-edittext-cursor-color)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6225995/can-i-change-the-cursor-size-in-android-edit-text-field

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Build your new drawable for cursor for example name it my_custom_cursor_drawable.xml in the drawable folder

```
my_custom_cursor_drawable.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"     android:shape="rectangle" >
<size android:width="0.5dp" />
<solid android:color="#FF0910DD"/>!--Could be any color you want
</shape>
```

The EditBox where you want this custom cursor set the property as

```
 android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/cursor_drawable"
```

Thats it !! improvise if need be. Any drawable , any shape etc...

Answer (score 2):

You can define a custom drawable for the EditText Cursor and use it for EditText using `android:textCursorDrawable`.