# Android how to change the edittext cursor style

Tags: android, android-edittext, cursor

I want to customize the EditText slider style. See my screenshots below.

This is the default slider style:

[image: This is the default cursor Style]

This is what I want to see:

[image: This is the cursor style I want to customize.]

This may be a dumb question, but after a few hours Googling, I can only find ways to change the cursor color, but couldn't find an approach to change the slider style.

This is the code I am using for changing the cursor color (color_cursor.xml):

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
  <size android:width="2dp" />
  <solid android:color="#008000" />
</shape>
```

And I applied the "android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/color_cursor" to EditText.

Thanks.

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6225995/can-i-change-the-cursor-size-in-android-edit-text-field

Comment: That cursor is available in material design library. Wrap your EditText in a TextInputLayout.

Comment: You can try android:textCursorDrawable(...)

Comment: Thanks @onurtaskin, seems in this way I can only change the cursor color? I updated my post as well.

Comment: @GiapLee, thank you, I updated my post, I was using this way. But seems I can only change the cursor color. Could you please make more comment and let me know how to change the cursor slider style? Thanks.

Comment: @Boss, thanks, I will give that a try.

Comment: check this out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12910305/android-how-do-i-stop-a-pointer-appearing-below-an-edittext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An answer for myself (hope this will also help others):
After introducing the "Theme.material", the EditText will become the expected style. I will want to check out *Material Design*.

Answer (score 1):

```
android:textSelectHandle="@drawable/your_desired_drawable"
```

put this in your editText view. Set the drawable you prefer. Then change the color inside your drawable xml file.